# Access: update a crosstab form

Tags: forms, ms-access, crosstab

I have a form that is bound to a crosstab query. The relations the query is based on are:

```
Client            Person             Address
|--------|        |----------|       |----------|
|ID      |    |--1|ID        |1--|   |ID        |
|IdPerson|----|   |...       |   |---|IdPerson  |
|--------|        |----------|       |----------|
```

Now, the query is 'not updateable', so I set the 'Recordset Type' of the form to 'Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)', so that the form allows me to input data in the bound fields.

When I try to save (go to next record etc.) the form, it says "You need to fill 'IdPerson' field". But how can I know the value for it? I can't. So I wrote a handler for 'BeforeUpdate' event, where I would like to predict the ID, the new row in Person would get and set the IdPerson for Client and Address fields. I cannot find a way to do this, meaning where is the row that is about to be inserted stored and how do I modify it? And that's my question.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm not sure that if I provide the values for IdPerson, Access will actually save anything, as there are constraints on the relations. It will depend on the order it saves the tables. If you know better approach (preferably without subforms), please share.

Comment: Here are a few notes that may be of use : http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating